# Laravel - How to call function from trait boot

Tags: php, laravel, traits

I just create a Trait to generate slugs to my models:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait SlugGenerator
{
    public function slugGenerator($slug = null)
    {
        return $slug ?? 'UUIDGeneratorFunction';
    }

    public static function bootSlugGenerator()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            // How to call slugGenerator() function here?
            $model->slug = slugGenerator();
        });
    }
}
```

The question is: How to call the `slugGenerator()` function inside my trait boot?

And if I want to change the slug Generator from any model, the way I'm setting the `$slug` variable is right? Example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Traits\SlugGenerator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use SlugGenerator;

    public function slugGenerator($slug = null)
    {
        return 'customSlug';
    }
}
```

Comment: @MagnusEriksson error returned: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Using $this when not in object context

Comment: Ah. I missed that It's set as `static`. You need to instantiate the class before you can access non-static class methods. Or you could make the `slugGenerator()` method static as well.

Answer (score 0):

The event receives the instance of the model, so you can call the method on that instance:

```php
    public static function bootSlugGenerator()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->slug = $model->slugGenerator();
        });
    }
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events